# DIscord bot not joining a voice channel, yet there is no error message

Tags: python, discord

I use the command but nothing happens, no feedback at all, no error message no join, other command like sending messages work but the join one dosen't work.

```
    if message.content.startswith("% join"):
        @bot.command()
        async def join(ctx):
            channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
            await channel.connect()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mixed an `on_message` **event** with a **command**, that is not how it works/will work.

You can indeed either use an `on_message` event or a `command`.

**Have a look at both codes:**

```py
@bot.event # Make it an event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith("% join"):
        channel = message.author.voice.channel # Get the channel of the author of the message
        await channel.connect()

@bot.command()
async def join(ctx):
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    await channel.connect()
```